# Codewars says "not all code paths return a value" while solving C# problem - I wonder why?

Tags: c#, function

I was trying to solve a problem in Codewars `8 kyu` and when I'm done writing a solution it says:

> not all code paths return a value

This is my code

```cs
using System;

public static class Kata
{
  public static int Quadrant(int x, int y)
  {
    if(x > 0 && y > 0) return 1;
    else if(x < 0 && y > 0) return 2;
    else if(x < 0 && y < 0) return 3;
    else if(x > 0 && y < 0) return 4;
    //else return 0; // works very fine with this condition 
  }
}

/*  
    [TestCase(1, 2, 1)] return 1
    [TestCase(3, 5, 1)] return 1
    [TestCase(-10, 100, 2)] return 2
    [TestCase(-1, -9, 3)] return 3
    [TestCase(19, -56, 4)] return 4
    [TestCase(1, 1, 1)] return 1
    [TestCase(-60, -12, 3)] return 3
*/
```

Can someone help me to understand why it's not working?

I tried to google why it's not working and I read that the function has to return something but the compiler found a way to reach the end of the function without returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if `x` or `y` are `0`? Then none of your conditions are met, and no value is returned from `Kata.Quadrant`.

If you want to avoid this, ensure you either use `else` or have an unconditional return at the end of your method.